# grep lines matching a pattern, and the lines before and after the matching until different pattern

Tags: awk, grep

```
Start_pattern
abc
d End_pattern
Start_pattern
abc
d
ef
ghij 
klm
no End_pattern
Start_pattern
abc
def
hij End_pattern
Start_pattern
abc
dhi
jklm End_pattern
```

**Desired Output:**

To print lines between `Start_pattern` including `Search_pattern` `End_pattern` Start and End pattern inclusive.

```
Start_pattern
abc
d
ef
ghij 
klm
no End_pattern
Start_pattern
abc
def
hij End_pattern
```

In above file i want to search for `"ef"` and print lines between `"Strat_pattern"` and `"End_pattern"`.

1. have tried `grep -B[NUM] and -A[NUM]` which are not useful as there could be 
   unknown number of lines between search pattern "gef" and "Start_pattern" 
   and "End_pattern".
2. `grep`, `sed` , `awk` anything welcomed. preferentially one liner.
3. `sed -n '/BEGIN/,/END/p' *` works to print lines between `Search_pattern` which is `"def"` and `End_pattern`. but iam not able to print lines between `Start_pattern` and `"def"`
4. Multiple files present with multiple occurrences of search_pattern

Comment: wish there was an option for cross-site duplicate ;) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335497/get-text-between-start-pattern-and-end-pattern-based-on-pattern-between-start-an/335523#335523

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `gawk`, which supports multi char `RS`:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="End_pattern"}/ef/' file
```

Output:

```
Start_pattern
abc
d
ef
ghij 
klm
no End_pattern
Start_pattern
abc
def
hij End_pattern
```

Explanation:

```
# Split records based on the End_pattern
BEGIN{RS=ORS="End_pattern"}

# Print records that contain the search term
/ef/
```

Btw, for cosmetic reasons you might want to append a newline at the end out the output:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="End_pattern"}/ef/;END{printf "\n"}' file
```

---

PS: While the above solution works with `gawk` only, it is also possible to achieve that with a simple `awk` script which is compatible to POSIX, meaning it works with any `awk`:

```
awk '{b=b$0"\n"}/End_pattern/{if(b~/ef/){printf "%s",b};b=""}' file
```

Explanation:

```
# Append the current line plus a newline to b(uffer)
{b=b$0"\n"}

# Once End_pattern is found ...
/End_pattern/{
    # Check if the buffer contains the search term
    if(b~/ef/){
        # Print the buffer when the term was found
        printf "%s",b
    }
    # Clear the buffer
    b=""
}

awk '{b=b$0"\n"}/End_pattern/{if(b~/ef/){printf "%s",b};b=""}' file
```

Comment: multi char RS is gawk specific... and OP mentions that both start/end lines are needed in output.. which is easy to add, other than some empty lines - `awk 'BEGIN{RS="End_pattern"} /ef/{print $0 RS}'`

Comment: Yeah, `RS` is `gawk` specific, that's true. About the start, end pattern, I think I was clear about that.

Comment: about the start/end lines, OP might have some needed details in actual use case or needed for further processing.. so I don't think it is okay to assume they are superfluous..

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. Sorry :)

Comment: Nice and clean solution. Maybe mention that this only works if there are no lines between `End_pattern` and `Start_pattern`. Imagine a space after `End_pattern`.

Comment: @kvantour A Space after `End_pattern` wouldn't be a problem. Also a newline wouldn't be a problem. It would just make it unchanged into the output file.

Comment: @hek2mgl Ah yes, it would indeed just appear again in the output on the same place. You are right, it is not a problem.

Comment: That would produce output even if `Start_pattern` didn't exist in the input as long as `ef` and `End_pattern` did. It'd also read the whole file into memory if `End_pattern` didn't exist.

Comment: I agree with that `Start_pattern` issue. However, how will you avoid that the whole file needs to get buffered in memory when `End_pattern` isn't there? (That applies to your answer too)

Comment: Thanks @hek2mgl  for clear solution. works perfectly.

Comment: some of files were `gz` files. hence i have used 
`zcat -f  * | gawk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="End_pattern"}/ef/'` which works on linux terminal. 
but Iam using a batch script on windows to connect to linux server with `plink.exe`. and redirecting `awk` result into `.txt` file on windows. 
after adding `zcat -f  *` with your awk statement the batch script is crashing. and iam unable to catch the error as `cmd` window is getting closed abruptly.

Comment: @hek2mgl mine would only buffer from the first Start_pattern which is unavoidable and it's likely that if End_pattern is missing then so is Start_pattern in which case mine will buffer nothing while yours would buffer the whole file.

Comment: @drake7788 Hard to reproduce for me on Linux. If you can describe the problem in a reproducible way I'd recommend to open a separate question for that problem.

Comment: @EdMorton Well, we are just speculating. But sure my script makes some assumptions about the validity of the input and is not defensive.

Comment: What I'm talking about is just satisfying the stated requirement to print the text between X and Y if it contains Z (or as the OP said `To print lines between Start_pattern including Search_pattern End_pattern Start and End pattern inclusive.`). Your script doesn't do that, it prints from the line after the last occurrence of Y (or start of the file) to the current Y if Z exists between the 2 Ys. It's got absolutely nothing to do with X but you cant tell that from the posted sample input. That's all I was pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness I add the `sed` solution here :

```
sed -n '/Start_pattern/{:a;N;/End_Pattern/!ba;/ef/p}'
```

To understand this, you need to think of labels and branches as [`goto` statements](https://xkcd.com/292/)

- If `Start_pattern` is found execute what is between `{...}`
- Define a label `a` with `:a`
- Add the line to the previous record. (`N`)
- If `End_Pattern` is found do not goto label `a` (`!ba`)
- After `End_Pattern` is found, execute the last part which states that if the full record contains `ef`, print the record.

Comment: Thanks @kvantour this `sed` solution works for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

adapting from my answer on another site - [Get text between start pattern and end pattern based on pattern between start and end pattern](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335497/get-text-between-start-pattern-and-end-pattern-based-on-pattern-between-start-an/335523#335523)

```
$ awk '/Start_pattern/{f=1; m=0; buf = $0; next}
       /ef/ && f{m=1}
       f{buf = buf ORS $0}
       /End_pattern/ && f{f=0; if(m==1)print buf}
      ' ip.txt
Start_pattern
abc
d
ef
ghij 
klm
no End_pattern
Start_pattern
abc
def
hij End_pattern
```

- `/Start_pattern/{f=1; m=0; buf = $0; next}` set flag to indicate start of block, clear match, initialize buffer and move on to next line
- `/ef/ && f{m=1}` if line contains `ef`, set match. `f` is used to avoid matching `ef` outside of `Start_pattern...End_pattern`
- `f{buf = buf ORS $0}` as long as flag is set, accumulate input lines
- `/End_pattern/ && f{f=0; if(m==1)print buf}` at end of block, print buffer if match was found

Comment: Instead of testing the same condition `f` 3 separate times, test it once and test the other conditions inside the block where `f` is true.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/Start_pattern/ { fnd=1; buf="" }
fnd {
    buf = buf $0 ORS
    if (/End_pattern/) {
        if (buf ~ /ef/) {
            printf "%s", buf
        }
        fnd = 0
        buf = ""
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Start_pattern
abc
d
ef
ghij
klm
no End_pattern
Start_pattern
abc
def
hij End_pattern
```